# Write SQL sum with join and group by in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I wish to write a query from SQL Server to laravel.

I want to write like this SQL:

```
select SUM(TRANSTKD.TRD_U_PRC) as prctotal from DOCINFO
inner join [TRANSTKH] on [DOCINFO].[DI_KEY] = [TRANSTKH].[TRH_DI] 
inner join [SKUMASTER] 
inner join [TRANSTKD] 
on [TRANSTKD].[TRD_SKU] = [SKUMASTER].[SKU_KEY] 
on [TRANSTKH].[TRH_KEY] = [TRANSTKD].[TRD_TRH] 
where [DOCINFO].[DI_KEY] = 148978
GROUP BY [SKUMASTER].[SKU_CODE];
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below laravel query

```
DB::table('DOCINFO')
    ->join('TRANSTKH', 'DOCINFO.DI_KEY', '=', 'TRANSTKH.TRH_DI')
    ->join('TRANSTKD', 'TRANSTKH.TRH_KEY', '=', 'TRANSTKD.TRD_TRH')
    ->join('SKUMASTER', 'TRANSTKD.TRD_SKU', '=', 'SKUMASTER.SKU_KEY')
    ->select(DB::raw('SUM(TRANSTKD.TRD_U_PRC) as prctotal'))
    ->where('DOCINFO.DI_KEY',148978)
    ->groupBy('SKUMASTER.SKU_CODE')
    ->get();
```

Let me know how it helps you!